# Is there another way in java 1.1 to handle cookies in Applets other than JSObject

Tags: java, browser, cookies, applet

wish you all a happy and exciting year of 2010.

Is there another way in java 1.1 to handle cookies in Applets other than using JSObject...

Answer (score 2):

How about doing all the cookie handling in Javascript and then having the Javascript code communicate the relevant data to the Applet object by invoking certain methods on it.

Note that an Applet is represented in the DOM as a good-old Javascript object which you can invoke methods on. The methods that it provides are the same as those defined by the Java class implementing the Applet.

Comment: Smart answer... thank you.
is there another way from java itself?